# UB со сдвигами беззнаковых переменных

Tags: c++

Код следующий:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  unsigned int a = 1;
  unsigned int b = 5;
  unsigned int c = (a << (a << b)) << b;
  std::cout << "s  : c \t\t= " << c << std::endl;;
  unsigned int x = 32u;
  std::cout << "s  : 1u<<x \t= " << (1u << x) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Компилирую в mingw (аналог gcc в винде). Под линуксом также пробовал через gcc - результат такой же. В зависимости от уровня оптимизации разный результат:

-O0:

```
s  : c          = 32
s  : 1u<<x      = 1
```

-O2:

```
s  : c          = 0
s  : 1u<<x      = 0
```

В коде по-видимому есть UB, но найти я его не могу, кажется, что там идут сдвиги беззнаковых переменных, а они UB не являются, и по логике оба ответа должны быть нулями.

[Цитата с cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> For unsigned a, the value of a << b is the value of a * 2^b , reduced
> modulo 2^N  where N is the number of bits in the return type (that is,
> bitwise left shift is performed and the bits that get shifted out of
> the destination type are discarded).

Что тут не так?

Comment: Сдвиг на число бит большее чем разрядность числа или равная разрядности числа - UB.

Comment: "The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand".

Comment: А можете дать ссылку на стандарт? Потому что на cppreference из написанного следует, что беззнаковые можно сколько угодно туда сюда сдвигать, или же я неправильно понял английский...

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift

Comment: Спасибо. Странно, что я тут завис - я эту статью пару лет назад читал в стандарте...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это UB согласно стандарту ([7.6.7 Shift operators](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift)):

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater
> than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand.